# Named parameters, caching and PDO

Tags: php, sql, mysql, pdo

If i have a parameterized SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_field = :field_value
```

Does anyone know if PDO will recognize this(see below) as the same SQL statement and use the cache instead of assuming it's a completely different SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE my_field = :new_field_value
```

So, I guess the question is: if the name of a parameter changes in a parameterized select statement but nothing else changes, will I still get the performance benefit of caching?  Or do I have to make sure that the parameter name stays the same?

Comment: "SELECT *" always makes me shudder.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using PDO_MySQL, it rewrites prepared statements into raw SQL on its own before the server even sees them, unless you set `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to false.

Comment: Doesn't that suggest that there's no performance benefit whatsoever to parameterization when using PDO with default attributes?

Comment: @Karim: Yes, pretty much. The default's there to make it work with MySQL 4.x. On top of no performance gains, PDO's rewriter is pretty buggy and doesn't handle edge cases well (it broke my code a few times until I learned to turn it off).

Comment: do you have a link supporting this? the manual says it takes advantage of native prepared statements in mysql 4.1 or higher. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

Comment: ill be damned...even on php5.4 using mysqlnd and a recent mysql version, PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES was on by default and my general query log doesn't show prepared statements unless i turn emulation off.

Answer (score 1):

It should be recognized as the same statement since the caching is done after the query parameters are replaced by values

Comment: Oh okay.  I was under the impression that parameterization is useful for performance because caching can be done without worrying about the actual values that are part of the query.  But it sounds like you're saying that caching is done with the given values.

Answer (score 0):

PDO has no cache - MySql does. And yes, it will cache the "final" query in the query cache. Not only that, but if you use use the same prepared statements multiple times, you will gain an additional speed increase, because MySql can cache the query execution plan for that statement.

Comment: So are you saying that it doesn't matter what name I use for parameters? As long as the syntax of the query is the same, i get the caching benefits?

Comment: No, you need to hold on to the prepared statement, to re-use it. But you can call it multiple times, binding different values each time, and get a slight benefit from that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how PDO handles named parameters but if it uses MySQL prepared statements then you will need to use MySQL 5.1.17 or later if you want it to use the query cache.

[MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-how.html)

> Before MySQL 5.1.17, prepared statements do not use the query cache. Beginning with 5.1.17, prepared statements use the query cache under certain conditions, which differ depending on the preparation method: